# In Ruby, how do I invoke system with an array, without eval?

Tags: ruby, arrays, arguments

I want to build up a command as an array of strings, and the invoke it through system, but I don't want to invoke the shell.

```
# I want this to echo '*'
f=['echo', '*']
system(f)
```

If I join the array with spaces, I get a shell expansion, so that's out.

Obviously I can use eval, but that seems ugly, and a bit risky if my strings contain ' - and uglier still if I add code to handle that:

```
eval "system('#{f.join("','")}')"
```

Seems there should be a better way - is there?

Thanks.

Comment: `system(*f)` and/or `\`#{f.join(' ')}\`` (note the backticks!) would do the trick, depending on what you expect to yield.

Comment: Backticks invoke a shell too. `system(*f)` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks commenters, while looking up capturing the output of system, I found

```
 system(*f)
```

in the context of using Open3.capture3() instead.